# KeyError 0 on <dl> tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse HTML site, but I have KeyError.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165"

#PL: otwiera połączenie z wybraną stroną, pobieranie zawartości strony (urllib)
#EN: Opens a connection and grabs url

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing (BeautifulSoup)
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #html.parser -> zapisujemy do html, nie np. do xml

#PL: zbiera tabelkę z numerami ofert, kuchnią i innymi danymi o nieruchomości z tabelki
#EN: grabs the data about real estate like kitchen, offer no, etc.
containers = page_soup.findAll("section",{"class":"clearfix"},{"id":"quick-summary"})

# print(len(containers)) - len(containers) sprawdza ile takich obiektów istnieje na stronie
#PL: Co prawda na stronie jest tylko jedna taka tabelka, ale dla dobra nauki zrobię tak jak gdyby tabelek było wiele.
#EN: There is only one table, but for the sake of knowledge I do the container variable
container = containers[0]
print(len(container.dl))
print(container.dl[0])
```

And this is the log with an error, that shows.

```
runfile('/home/bartosz/Pulpit/web_scrap.py', wdir='/home/bartosz/Pulpit')
36
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-70-e826e21c585a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/bartosz/Pulpit/web_scrap.py', wdir='/home/bartosz/Pulpit')

  File "/home/bartosz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/bartosz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/bartosz/Pulpit/web_scrap.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(container.dl[0])

  File "/home/bartosz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]

KeyError: 0
```

The len(container.dl) shows that there is 36 in dl's. If I do len(container.dl.dt), it shows: 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the contents of element not through direct indexing, but through `.contents` property:

```
print(container.dl.contents[0])
```

should work.

With direct indexing you are accessing attributes of tags, eg. if it was `<dl class="myclass">` then `dl['class']` will print `myclass`.

EDIT:

To print all content of `container.dl`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165"

with uReq(my_url) as uClient:
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")

container = page_soup.findAll("section",{"class":"clearfix"},{"id":"quick-summary"})[0]

print(len(container.dl))
print('-' * 80)
for content in container.dl.contents:
    print(content)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints (first row is length of `container.dl.contents`):

```
36
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Numer oferty</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>351165</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Liczba pokoi</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>4</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Cena</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd><span class="tag price">339 600 PLN</span></dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Cena za m2</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>5 096 PLN</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Powierzchnia</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>66,64 m2</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Piętro</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>1</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Liczba pięter</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>6</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Typ kuchni</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Aneks</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Balkon</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Tak</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Rodzaj ogrzewania</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>CO miejskie</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Gorąca woda</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Wodociąg miejski</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Rodzaj budynku</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Wysoki blok</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Materiał</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Silikat</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Rok budowy</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>2019</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Winda</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Tak</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Stan nieruchomości</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Stan deweloperski</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dt>Rynek</dt>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<dd>Pierwotny</dd>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Something happens. I did print(container.dl.dt.contents), but it is only showing the first one in a list as ['Numer oferty']. I don't know why I doesn't see the rest of dt's.

Comment: @BartBart I edited my answer, I printed all `container.dl.contents`

Comment: Thanks! I managed in other way, but yours seems easier. Btw. here is the project subject, I you'd like to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592631/real-estate-market-scrapping-using-python-and-beautifulsoup