# Real Estate Market Scraping using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some concept how to parse a real estate market using Python. I've searched some information about parsing the websites, I even did this in VBA, but I would like to do it in python.

This is the site which will be parsed (it's one offer only now, but it will be working on full range of real estate offers, multiple sites from kontrakt.szczecin.pl):
http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-100m2-335000pln-grudziadzka-pomorzany-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351149

First of all, program will use 3 pieces of information:

1/ **The table where is information (Main parameters):**
Numer oferty 351149, Liczba pokoi 3, Cena 335 000 PLN, Cena za m2 3 350 PLN (Number of offer, Room no, Price, Price by square meter etc). However the quantity of information depends on property offer: sometimes is 14, sometimes is 12, sometimes 16 etc.

2/ **Description of property in paragraphs (it is another part of program, for now it can be skipped)**: Sometimes in the table (1/) there is information that there is garage or balcony. But in paragraph there is a sentence that garage is for additional price (which means for me that property doesn't have garage) or balcony is in French type (which is no balcony for me).
I managed that program should find the correct word in paragraph (such as garage) and copy text from paragraph with additional text on the left and right side (for instance: 20 letters in both sides, but what if the word is in the first place?)

3/ **Additional Parameters** -
Not every offer has it but like this one (http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165) there is information about number of balconies in property. Sometimes there is information about basement too. It should be similar code to the 1/ issue.

So I tried something like this, using some internet sources (it is still incomplete):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165"

#PL: otwiera połączenie z wybraną stroną, pobieranie zawartości strony (urllib)
#EN: Opens a connection and grabs url

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing (BeautifulSoup)
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser") #html.parser -> zapisujemy do html, nie np. do xml

#PL: zbiera tabelkę z numerami ofert, kuchnią i innymi danymi o nieruchomości z tabelki
#EN: grabs the data about real estate like kitchen, offer no, etc.
containers = page_soup.findAll("section",{"class":"clearfix"},{"id":"quick-summary"})

# print(len(containers)) - len(containers) sprawdza ile takich obiektów istnieje na stronie
#PL: Co prawda na stronie jest tylko jedna taka tabelka, ale dla dobra nauki zrobię tak jak gdyby tabelek było wiele.
#EN: There is only one table, but for the sake of knowledge I do the container variable
container = containers[0]
find_dt = container.findAll("dt")
find_dd = container.findAll("dd")
print(find_dt[0].text + " " + find_dd[0])
```

It works, but still is incomplete. I don't continue it right now because there is major flaw. As you see the last print it takes indexes, but not every property will have the same order (because as I mentioned sometimes there is 10 pieces of info, sometimes more, sometimes less). It will be a huge mess in CSV.

My VBA program worked in this way:

1. Copy table to Excel (Sheet 1)
2. In the sheet 2 there was parameters that program was looking for (such as Prices)
3. Mechanism in shortcut: Copy parameter from sheet 2 (Price), go to sheet 1 (where is parsed information), find Price string (paste the information from sheet 2: "Price"), go line below, copy price value, go to sheet 2, find Price, go below, paste the price value. And so on.

Looking for help with concept and coding also.

EDIT:
PART 1 and PART 2 is ready. But I have big issues with PART 3. Here is the code:

```
from urllib import request as uReq
import requests
#dzięki temu program jest zamykany odrazu, i nie kontynuuje wykonywania reszty kodu. Po imporcie wystarczy exit(0)
from sys import exit
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
import re
import itertools

filename = 'test.txt'

#licznik, potrzebny do obliczenia ilości numerów ofert w pliku .txt
num_lines = 0

# tworzymy listę danych i listę URLi. Wyniki będą dodawane do list, dlatego potrzeba jest ich utworzenia (jako puste)
list_of_lines = ['351238', '351237', '111111', '351353']
list_of_lines2 = []
list_of_URLs = []
list_of_redictered_URLs = []
KONTRAKT = 'http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl'

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        #dodajemy linię (ofertę) do listy
        list_of_lines.append(line.strip())
        #num_lines jest licznikiem, wskazuje ile wierszy zawiera lista, zmienna jest istotna w zakresię tworzenia pętli z adresami URL
        num_lines += 1

#tworzymy URLe z Numerów Ofert zawartych w filename

for i in range(num_lines):
    nr_oferty = list_of_lines[i]
    my_url = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/lista-ofert/?f_listingId=" + nr_oferty + "&f=&submit=Szukaj"
    list_of_URLs.append(my_url)
print(list_of_URLs)




#Cześć druga: konwertowanie listy linków na listę linków przekierowanych

#Program wchodzi na stronę, która powinna być przekierowana, jednak ze względu na użyscie Java Scriptu,
#zadanie zostało utrudnione. Dlatego, też celem programu jest symulowanie przeglądarki, pobranie
#zawartości strony, a następnie 'wyłuskanie' odpowiedniego linku do przekierowania

i = 0
for i in range(num_lines):
    url_redirect = list_of_URLs[i]
    my_url = url_redirect
    BROWSER = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(my_url, headers=BROWSER)
    script1 = '<script>'
    script2 = '</script>'
    content_URL = str(response.content)
    find_script1 = (content_URL.find(script1))
    find_script2 = (content_URL.find(script2))
    url_ready = content_URL[find_script1:find_script2]
    print(i+1,'z', num_lines, '-', 'oferta nr:', str(my_url[57:57+6]))
    list_of_redictered_URLs.append(url_ready)

#usuwanie zbędnych tagów i znaków, w celu uzyskania czystego przekierowanego linku
list_of_redictered_URLs = [w.replace('<script>window.location=\\\'','') for w in list_of_redictered_URLs]
list_of_redictered_URLs = [w.replace('\\\';','') for w in list_of_redictered_URLs]
#print(list_of_redictered_URLs)
#usuwanie pustych wierszy z listy (oferty, które są nieakutalne na liste "wchodzą jako puste" !!! item: jest to zmienna, można zamienić np. na janusz.
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda item: item.strip(), list_of_redictered_URLs))
filtered_list = [KONTRAKT + item for item in filtered_list]
#zmiana na tuple, ze względu iż mutowalność (dodawanie kolejnych linków) nie będzie potrzebne
filtered_list = tuple(filtered_list)

#print(str(filtered_list))

print('Lista linków:\n',filtered_list)

# Kolejną częścią programu jest pobieranie istotnych informacji (parametrów podstawowych)
# ze strony kontrakt.szczecin.pl, a następnie ich zapisanie w pliku csv.

# Nagłówki w csv oraz nazwy parametrów na stronie (muszą być identyczne jak na stronie, aby mogły
# zostać odpowiednio przyporządkowane w .csv)

HEADERS = ['Numer oferty',
           'Liczba pokoi',
           'Cena',
           'Cena za m2',
           'Powierzchnia',
           'Piętro',
           'Liczba pięter',
           'Typ kuchni',
           'Balkon',
           'Czynsz administracyjny',
           'Rodzaj ogrzewania',
           'Umeblowanie',
           'Wyposażona kuchnia',
           'Gorąca woda',
           'Rodzaj budynku',
           'Materiał',
           'Rok budowy',
           'Stan nieruchomości',
           'Rynek',
           'Dach:',
           'Liczba balkonów:',
           'Liczba tarasów:',
           'Piwnica:',
           'Ogród:',
           'Ochrona:',
           'Garaż:',
           'Winda:',
           'Kształt działki:',
           'Szerokość działki (mb.):',
           'Długość działki (mb.):',
           'Droga dojazdowa:',
           'Gaz:',
           'Prąd:',
           'Siła:','piwnica',
            'komórk',
            'strych',
            'gospodarcze',
            'postojow',
            'parking',
            'przynależn',
            'garaż',
            'ogród',
            'ogrod',
            'działka',
            'ocieplony',
            'moderniz',
            'restaur',
            'odnow',
            'ociepl',
            'remon',
            'elew',
            'dozór',
            'dozor',
            'monitoring',
            'monit',
            'ochron',
            'alarm',
            'strzeż',
            'portier',
            'wspólnot',
            'spółdziel',
            'kuchni',
            'aneks',
            'widna',
            'ciemna',
            'prześwit',
            'oficyn',
            'linia',
            'zabudow',
            'opłat',
            'bezczynsz',
            'poziom',
            'wind',
            'francuski',
            'ul.',
            'w cenie',
            'dodatkową']

LINKI = ["Link"]

#HEADERS2 = ['Liczba balkonów:',
#           'Liczba tarasów:',
#           'Piwnica:',
#           'Ogród:',
#           'Ochrona:',
#           'Garaż:',
#           'Winda:']

HEADERS3 = ['piwnica',
            'komórk',
            'strych',
            'gospodarcze',
            'postojow',
            'parking',
            'przynależn',
            'garaż',
            'ogród',
            'ogrod',
            'działka',
            'ocieplony',
            'moderniz',
            'restaur',
            'odnow',
            'ociepl',
            'remon',
            'elew',
            'dozór',
            'dozor',
            'monitoring',
            'monit',
            'ochron',
            'alarm',
            'strzeż',
            'portier',
            'wspólnot',
            'spółdziel',
            'kuchni',
            'aneks',
            'widna',
            'ciemna',
            'prześwit',
            'oficyn',
            'linia',
            'zabudow',
            'opłat',
            'bezczynsz',
            'poziom',
            'wind',
            'francuski',
            'ul.',
            'w cenie',
            'dodatkową',]

csv_name = 'data.csv'
print('Dane zostaną zapisane do pliku:',csv_name + '.csv')
print('\n>>>>Program rozpoczyna pobieranie danych')
#Pobieranie linków

i = 0  
#Tworzy plik csv o nazwie csv
#writerow może mieć tylko jeden argument, dlatego jest nim suma poszczególnych list. Lista
#linki ma jędną pozycję, ponieważ można sumować dane jednego typu. Nie można sumować listy ze stringami.
with open(csv_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    HEADERS_ALL = HEADERS+HEADERS3+LINKI
    csvwriter.writerow(HEADERS_ALL)

    for i in range(len(filtered_list)):
        my_url = filtered_list[i]
        with uReq2(my_url) as uClient:
            page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), 'lxml')
            print('\t\t-----------',i+1,'-----------\n',my_url)


        #<dt> - nazwa parametru np. Kuchnia
        #<dd> - wartość parametru np. widna   
        row = ['-'] * len(HEADERS) + ['-'] * len(HEADERS3) + ['-'] * len(LINKI)
        # Parametry podstawowe (kontrakt.szczecin.pl)
        for dt, dd in zip(page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dt'), page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dd')):
            if dt.text.strip() not in HEADERS:
                print("\n 1(dt,dd):UWAGA!, kolumna [{}] nie istnieje w nagłówkach! (stała: HEADERS)\n".format(dt.text.strip()))
                continue
            row[HEADERS.index(dt.text.strip())] = dd.text.strip()

        # Parametry dodatkowe
        for span, li in zip(page_soup.select('section#property-features span'), page_soup.select('section#property-features li')):
            if span.text.strip() not in HEADERS:
                print("\n 2:UWAGA(span,li), kolumna [{}] nie istnieje w nagłówkach (stała HEADERS)!\n".format(span.text.strip()))
                continue
            row[HEADERS.index(span.text.strip())] = li.text.strip()
        #csvwriter.writerow(row)
        print(row)

#No to zaczynamy zabawę...................................

        # zmienna j odnosi się do indeksu HEADERS3, jest to j nie i, ponieważ i jest w dalszym użyciu
        # w pętli powyżej

        for p in page_soup.select('section#description'):
            p = str(p)
            p = p.lower() 


            for j in range(len(HEADERS3)): 
                #print('j:',j)
                # find_p znajduje wszystkie słowa kluczowe z HEADERS3 w paragrafie na stronie kontraktu.
                find_p = re.findall(HEADERS3[j],p)
                # listy, które wyświetlają pozycję startową poszczególnych słów muszą zaczynać się od '-' lub 0?,
                # ponieważ, gdy dane słowo nie zostanie odnalezione to listy będą puste w pierwszej iteracji pętli
                # co w konsekewncji doprowadzi do błędu out of range
                m_start = []
                m_end = []
                lista_j = []

                for m in re.finditer(HEADERS3[j], p):
                    #print((m.start(),m.end()), m.group())
                    m_start.append(m.start())
                    m_end.append(m.end())

                #print(h)

                for k in range(len(m_start)):
                    #właściwe teraz nie wiem po co to jest..
                    try:
                        x = m_start[k]
                        y = m_end[k]
                    except IndexError:
                        x = m_start[0]
                        y = m_end[0]
                    #print('xy:',x,y)
                    #print(find_p) 
                #print(HEADERS3[j])
                    z = (HEADERS3[j]+':',p[-60+x:y+60]+'    ++-NNN-++') 
                    lista_j.append(z)
                print (lista_j)


        print(str(lista_j))
        row[HEADERS.index(span.text.strip())] = str(lista_j)
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
        #print(row)
```

Comment: I don't have right now the internet connection in my computer with python, but I thought to add to the code above these piece with creating the list:
base = [], if find_dt[0].text == "Numer oferty": v1 = find_dd[0].text base.insert (v1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet will parse the quick summary table of the property url and saves it in csv file:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

# my_url = 'http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165'
my_url = 'http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-100m2-335000pln-grudziadzka-pomorzany-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351149'

with uReq(my_url) as uClient:
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), 'lxml')


with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for dt, dd in zip(page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dt'), page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dd')):
        csvwriter.writerow([dt.text.strip(), dd.text.strip()])
```

The result is in `data.csv`, screenshot from my LibreOffice:

[image]

For having the table transposed, you can use this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

# my_url = 'http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-6664m2-339600pln-potulicka-nowe-miasto-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351165'
my_url = 'http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/mieszkanie-sprzedaz-100m2-335000pln-grudziadzka-pomorzany-szczecin-zachodniopomorskie,351149'

with uReq(my_url) as uClient:
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), 'lxml')

headers = ['Numer oferty',
           'Liczba pokoi',
           'Cena',
           'Cena za m2',
           'Powierzchnia',
           'Piętro',
           'Liczba pięter',
           'Typ kuchni',
           'Balkon',
           'Czynsz administracyjny',
           'Rodzaj ogrzewania',
           'Gorąca woda',
           'Rodzaj budynku',
           'Materiał',
           'Rok budowy',
           'Stan nieruchomości',
           'Rynek',
           'Dach:',
           'Liczba balkonów:',
           'Piwnica:',
           'Kształt działki:',
           'Szerokość działki (mb.):',
           'Długość działki (mb.):',
           'Droga dojazdowa:',
           'Gaz:',
           'Prąd:',
           'Siła:']

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    csvwriter.writerow(headers)

    row = ['-'] * len(headers)
    for dt, dd in zip(page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dt'), page_soup.select('section#quick-summary dd')):
        if dt.text.strip() not in headers:
            print("Warning, column [{}] doesn't exist in headers!".format(dt.text.strip()))
            continue
        row[headers.index(dt.text.strip())] = dd.text.strip()
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

The result will be in csv file like this (the values not present will be substituted with '-'):

[image]

Comment: @AndrejKasely Cool! I thought about more 'cody' way using if statements on variables. However, I'd like to see a transposed table. <dt> would be the header, and rows would be data from <dd> (I think it will be change in the code from: csvwriter.writerow to writecol or writecolumn? :>). Btw. what is zip in the code?

Comment: Full range of <dt> from different offers: Numer oferty, Liczba pokoi, Cena, Cena za m2, Powierzchnia, Piętro, Liczba pięter, Typ kuchni, Balkon, Czynsz administracyjny, Rodzaj ogrzewania, Gorąca woda, Rodzaj budynku Materiał, Rok budowy, Stan nieruchomości, Rynek, Dach:, Liczba balkonów:, Piwnica:, Kształt działki:, Szerokość działki (mb.):, Długość działki (mb.):, Droga dojazdowa:, Gaz:, Prąd:, Siła:.

Comment: @BartBart I updated my answer - see the second screenshot. The `zip()` function takes any number of iterables and "zips" them together (docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). `list(zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']))` will become `[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]`.

Comment: @Andrej_Kesely Yes, thanks. That will help me a lot with the project. Thank you for information about zip.

Comment: @Andrej_Kesely I nearly made it, but have some big issues with last part. Could you check it? I need to put last data into the csv

Comment: I need to add, whole lists to one list and make a row I think